# How do you configure a sequential workflow on CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, circleci

I've added a config.yml file to a react-native project in the .circleci/ directory in order to configure a build pipeline.

But in my CircleCI 2.0 server only the first job, `build` runs while `test` and `android` don't run although they are part of the overall workflow config.

I've followed the workflow configuration guide here https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/ to configure a sequential workflow.

I did verify that my CI server is using the config below

Question:

How do you configure a sequential workflow on CircleCI 2.0?

**config.yml file in repo:**

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
    #
    # Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
    #
    version: 2
    machine:
      environment:
        PATH: "${PATH}:${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/node_modules/.bin"

    dependencies:
      override:
        - yarn
        - jest
      cache_directories:
        - ~/.cache/yarn
        - ~/.cache/jest

    build:
      override:
        - yarn install



    jobs:
       build:
        working_directory: ~/repo
        docker:
          - image: circleci/node:8
        steps:
          - checkout
          - run: yarn install
          - persist_to_workspace:
              root: ~/repo
              paths:
                - node_modules  
        test:
          working_directory: ~/repo
          docker:
            - image: circleci/node:8.9.0
          steps:
            - checkout
            - run: yarn install
            - run: npm test
            - persist_to_workspace:
                root: ~/repo
                paths:
                  - node_modules         
        android:
          working_directory: ~/repo/android
          docker:
            - image: circleci/android:api-27-node8-alpha
          steps:
            - checkout:
                path: ~/repo
            - attach_workspace:
                at: ~/repo
            - run: bundle install
            #- run: bundle exec fastlane test
            - store_test_results:
              path: ~/root/android/reports


    workflows:
      version: 2
      node-android:
        jobs:
          - build:
              filters:
                tags:
                  ignore: /^testing
          - test   
              requires:
                - test
          - android:
              requires:
                - test
                - build
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at this doc (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/). This config file is combining both CircleCI 1.0 and 2.0 syntax. You'd want to remove all of the 1.0 syntax which is the dependency part near the top.

Comment: @FelicianoTech I'll take a look, I originally added the dependency part as yarn install command wouldn't work and was defaulting to an npm install

Comment: @FelicianoTech I got the workflows running but did notice a problem with env var not being found on the android job, if you have any tips on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163104/how-to-resolve-term-not-set-on-gradlew-assemblerelease-on-circleci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the workflow by removing the CI 1.0 syntax as @FelicianoTech mentioend, this piece of YAML is not 2.0 CircleCI syntax:

```
machine:
      environment:
        PATH: "${PATH}:${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/node_modules/.bin"

    dependencies:
      override:
        - yarn
        - jest
      cache_directories:
        - ~/.cache/yarn
        - ~/.cache/jest

    build:
      override:
        - yarn install
```